# RemoveAt method of List is Not working

Tags: c#

Here is my list class

```
 public class ClosedProject : ViewModelBase
  {        
    private string _projectId;
    List<EmployeeOnProject> _employeeList;
    List<ModuleAllocation> _moduleList;
   }
```

below code is working fine i.e after execution of foreach loop employeeOnProject object gets removed from EmployeeOnProjectContainer(list of employeeOnProject)

```
foreach (EmployeeOnProject employeeOnProject in ClosedProject.EmployeeList)
 {
  if (employeeOnProject != null)
   {                                        
      EmployeeOnProjectContainer.RemoveAt(EmployeeOnProjectContainer.IndexOf(employeeOnProject));                                      
    }
 }
```

but same logic fails in below case

```
foreach (ModuleAllocation moduleAllocation in ClosedProject.ModuleList)
 {
   if (moduleAllocation != null)
   {
       ModuleAllocationContainer.RemoveAt(ModuleAllocationContainer.IndexOf(moduleAllocation));
    }
 }
```

I have also tried simple remove method

Comment: What do you mean by *fails*, you get an error?

Comment: You can't alter collection in ForEach loop.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen It's a different collection.

Comment: Alrighty then, Maybe the loaded objects are not the same in memory then?

Comment: it throws exception "Index out out of range", and i have checked index while debugging it returns -1, ModuleList contains element same as ModulAllocationContainer still it returns -1 index.

Comment: What will happen if you remove two rows and one is at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the [`.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to firstly check...

```
foreach (ModuleAllocation moduleAllocation in ClosedProject.ModuleList)
 {
   if (moduleAllocation != null)
   {
       if (ModuleAllocationContainer.Contains(moduleAllocation))
        ModuleAllocationContainer.RemoveAt(ModuleAllocationContainer.IndexOf(moduleAllocation));
    }
 }
```

Otherwise, you're attempting to remove something that may potentially not be in the list.

**EDIT**: As [@Rawling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734957/removeat-method-of-list-is-not-working/23735232#comment36485764_23735232) pointed out, you could also do...

```
foreach (ModuleAllocation moduleAllocation in ClosedProject.ModuleList)
 {
   if (moduleAllocation != null)
   {
       var indexOf = ModuleAllocationContainer.IndexOf(moduleAllocation);
       if (indexOf != -1)
          ModuleAllocationContainer.RemoveAt(indexOf);
    }
 }
```

Comment: If you're going to check, check `IndexOf != -1` - otherwise you're searching the list twice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using Except() as such?

```
var list1 = new List<int>(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
var list2 = new List<int>(new int[] { 0, 2, 4 ,6, 8 });

var list3 = list1.Except(list2); // returns 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
```